# Java swing three relative comboboxes

Tags: java, swing, listener, jcombobox

I have three relative comboboxes lists that take data from the database, and if I change one, the other also changes through SetModel () method. The problem is that whenever a new pattern, the data in the other lists are changed, the listener again reacts to them. How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the listener again reacts to them

1. remove the listener
2. do your processing
3. add the listener back to the component

Comment: Maybe I did not adequately described the problem. The comboboxes are all linked between each other. And not known beforehand which one will be changed by user. I was already bypassed a problem, thank you for trying to help.

Comment: Well usually when you have linked combo boxes it works something like if you change box1, then box2 is updated. If you change box2, then box3 is updated. If you change box3, nothing happens. So there is always some kind of hierarchy in the structure. If you have some different structure then I guess I don't understand it. You need to pose a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.